# Single Table Inheritance in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I'm trying to implement a somewhat simple STI in Rails 4, but there's something I can't yet manage to achieve.

I have the following classes:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class NaturalPerson < Person
end

class LegalPerson < Person
end

class Employee < NaturalPerson
end

class Customer < NaturalPerson
end
```

The thing is, I have some attributes that I want to access only from the Employee class, some only from Customer, etc, but I can't find the way. If I were to be using Rails 3's way I would've solved it with attr_accesible. But this isn't posible now, since I'm neither using the attr_accesible gem, nor I'm willing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I woud use different person_params in my controller,

```
def person_params
params.require(:person).permit(:email, :last_name, :first_name)
end

def natural_person_params
params.require(:person).permit(:email, :job, :location)
end
```

and create a method where I would test the class name of object or the type attribute as it is a STI) to determine which params to use...

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: And what if I want to create a person outside of the controller? Is this also possible? I'm relatively new to Rails, so I might have a conceptual error here. Thanks!

Comment: Reading my comment again, I might not have been clear. What I meant was, what if I want to handle an instance of NaturalPerson outside the controller? How can I define an attribute accesible only for NaturalPerson? The way ActiveRecord handles the Person attributes, all children of Person will have access to all the attributes. Thanks!!!

Comment: Not sure, I did not test STI in Rails 4 yet (just fast read the docs).

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to use a single controller for all of the models, then put ALL the attributes into the white listed params.

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:email, :last_name, :first_name, :job, :location)
end
```

If you want to separate them, then you'll want separate params for each type of person:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:email, :last_name, :first_name)
end

def employed_person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:email, :job, :location)
end
```