# Rails 4.0 Devise 3.x and adding custom columns to STI User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I have a rails 4 app running devise 3.x and I am having trouble adding a `:first_name` column to my Player model. I have 2 separate models that inherit from a `User` model - `Player` and `Coach`

I followed [this 12 spokes](http://blog.12spokes.com/web-design-development/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4/#how-to) post but am having trouble rendering the registration form in development mode.

I have a class `PlayerParameterSanitizer` to override the devise [signup action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) and add the `:first_name` parameter

```
class PlayerParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def sign_up
    default_params.permit(:type, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name)
  end
end
```

and I create a new object of this class in the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == Player
      PlayerParameterSanitizer.new(Player,:player,params)
    elsif resource_class == Coach
      CoachParameterSanitizer.new(Coach,:coach,params)
    else
      super
    end    
  end

end
```

I'm loading the sanitizers in an initializer in `config/initializers/sanitizers.rb`

```
require "#{Rails.application.root}/lib/player_sanitizer.rb"
```

Yet, I'm still getting the

```
undefined method `first_name' for #<Player:0x00000101cafab0>
```

on the `view/players/registrations/new.html.erb` page. What am I missing here?

#### update

db schema

```
  create_table "players", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "first_name"
  end
```

#### Update #2

```
devise_for :players, :controllers => {:registrations => "players/registrations",
                                        :sessions => "players/sessions",
                                        :passwords => "players/passwords"}
```

models for unrelated sanity

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

Player class inheriting from User.

```
class Player < User

end
```

## Update #3

I shouldn't be using STI in this fashion, I don't think.

I want Coach and Player to share Devise Auth Functionality but Player will have additional fields to Coach (club, position, year, etc.)

With STI for rails 4 all attributes would be stored on the User table. But this means a Coach would have those fields but be saved in it's table as having nil for stuff like position, current club, etc.

That seems incorrect..

Basically, I want both Coach and Player to inherit from User so as to achieve devise functionality. But, I want Player to have several fields in addition to that of Coach.

Comment: could it be more of a problem with how my models are set up? added a `:first_name` to the User model and no longer getting the noMethodError

Comment: Not entirely sure why this approach isn't working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297797/add-custom-field-column-to-devise-with-rails-4 could it be because I'm overidding the devise controller? Moving this logic to Players controller..

Comment: Please See update number 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem after further research (http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) that with STI all attributes should be added to the `User` table. This will result (in my case) in `Coach` having `nil` values for the additional fields `Player` will have.

This can lead to scaling problems later on and is not so related to strong params + Devise for rails 4 as I had initially thought.

Answer (score 2):

You can use polymorphism as well and database attributes won't be shared. Something like the following:

```
class Login < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :user, polymorphic: true
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :login, as: :user
end


class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :login, as: :user
end
```

This is just to give you a rough idea. Notice that I haven't tried any of this and that probably special care is to be taken if you use a class not named User in Devise. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure your router is using the proper controllers too. Otherwise it will load the controllers from Devise (which is a Rails engine), try this in your router:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

Otherwise, I'd also take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793371/103739

Comment: I've updated my question with current `routes.rb` and also the models in question. Given the `NoMethodError` could it be that I'm overlooking something obvious about STI + Devise? Creating a new player in the console `player = User::Player.new` does not even yield a `:first_name` attribute reference. How can this be given the migrations ran correctly and the current schema? (I have tried recreating local db several times)

Comment: ok I understand the devise side of it but I think my question (initially unknowingly) is a question of STI related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480029/single-table-inheritance-in-rails-4